# IE 9 dotted lines around Checkbox

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

Problem with IE 9 and earlier IE browsers putting dotted lines around my checkboxs. It seems to want to call post textarea and post input adding a border around the checkbox and then calling post input focus and putting a background around it.

The dotted line wont go away even if I put border 0px in post input. No other browser FF, chrome does this....
Nothing to do with the checkbox .reset file

Image in IE 9: http://i46.tinypic.com/hvqj2g.png

Code Calling: http://i46.tinypic.com/30ic1f5.png

```
#post textarea,
#post input {
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}
#post textarea:focus {
     outline: none;
     ie-dummy: expression(this.hideFocus=true);
   }
#post input:focus {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #eee ;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #eee ;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px #eee ;
    background: #fefcbe;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

#post input#submit-btn{
    background: #eee;
    color:#444;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}


Any ideas for IE 9?
```

Comment: Well the dotted lines are gone with outline: none in post input but its still acting like a text box.

Answer (score 11):

The dotted line is “focus rectangle”, a usability feature that has unfortunately been implemented inconsistently in browsers. As you remark in your comment, it disappears if you set `outline: none` on the element; the focus rectangle is technically an outline resulting from a browser’s default style sheet. This means, among other things, that a person who uses the Tab key to move inside the page (possibly because he has to) will not see any focus indicator there, i.e. does not see where he is.

Depending on the state (Quirks Mode vs. “Standards” Mode) of IE 9, the focus rectangle appears around the checkbox, or around the associated label. The comments above apply to “Standards” mode.

Your issue of “its acting like a text box” as per your comment cannot be resolved without knowing what you mean by it and without having access to the code. Please post actual code or a URL of code, not a screenshot that contains an image of a fragment of code.

Comment: This happened to me when for Text boxes when I was using Bootstrap.js. Setting "Outline:None" solved the issue thanks.

Comment: Just be sure to add some kind of focus state back in for accessibility and general usability of your forms.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
element:focus{
 outline: thin transparent;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try using some javascript in your HTML element:

```
<input onclick="this.blur()" />
```

Comment: Why people are most of the time lazy to try to find a solution without using JS?